# WordPress multi-user site to allow unique users to see custom screens

Tags: wordpress, authentication, multi-user

So I need to set up a WordPress site with 25 users. The site will be for each of these users to fill out various forms (different forms for each user) and then these results will be stored on the database.

The thing is, I need to allow user1 to only be able to see the forms we want user1 to fill out, and the same for user2,3...etc. We have the bones of the site set up, but I'm looking for a plug-in or theme or something that can allow different users to see different pages. Is there one available?

Or would any you have any idea how to go about this another way?

I have spent the best part of a days searching but I can't find a viable solution. Any help would be *greatly* appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things can be done. 
Use Contact form 7 or Gravity form plugin to create different forms. Create user specific pages where you like to show forms. Paste corresponding form short-codes in the pages.

Use Role Scoper plugin to restrict users to see pages. You can set permissions for different user to see different pages.

Hope this helps you.